# Partial dependence plots are empty, partial dependence shows null list

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, xgboost

I'm trying to create partial dependence plots for a classification model (XGBClassifier). I was able to get variable importance, but some of the partial dependence plots for those variables are empty. These are the two functions I have tried:

```
PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(model, X_data, [variable])
plot_partial_dependence(model, X_data, [variable])
```

where `model` is my trained model, `X_data` is the dataset of variables, and `variable` is the specific trait that the partial dependence plot is not showing up for.

I also see that when I use the `partial_dependence| function to see the values, there are nan values where there should be numbers:

```
partial_dependence(model_type[0], X, [variable])
```

which gives me:

```
(array([[0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357,
         0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357, 0.11820357]],
       dtype=float32),
 [array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])])
```

when it should give me two arrays of non empty, unique numbers. I've tried a bunch of different things, but I can't figure out how to fix this, or where in my code there is an error that causes this problem.

Comment: I am facing same problems, do you find its solution @gowri ??

Comment: Does your data set have NULLs? I do not think that is handled